# Styles aren't being applied on some pages. No errors

Tags: magento2, css

Some css styles aren’t applying on some pages, but applying everywhere else.

I’ve removed view_preprocessed, cache, static/frontend and static/admin, run setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, static-content:deploy -f, and both cleared and flushed the cache

This is CSS only, no issues with XML

Answer (score 0):

The issue was showing up on 3 category pages. I found that I had "Use Parent Category Settings" set to "on" on those pages.

I turned it off, and the issue went away